# Neural Network bad results

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

i am working on a neural network. I am exploring the effect of using a larger dataset for training. Currently i am getting crappy results. Any suggestions? I dont want to use any libraries other than numpy and please keep things simple. I am a GCSE student so i do not know a great deal about calculus either. 
   To improve my network ive added:
       a second hidden layer,
       more epochs,
       a different activation function (reLU instead of sigmoid),
       more hidden nodes per layer
       ...but my results are still terrible!

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([
    [0000],
    [0001],
    [0010],
    [0100],
    [1000],
    [0011],
    [0110],
    [1100],
    [1001],
    [1001],
    [1110],
    [1101],
    [1011],
    [1111],
    [1111],
    [1111],
    [1111]
    ])

y = np.array([
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    ]).T

w = np.random.random((1, 1))
w2 = np.random.random((1, 1))
w3 = np.random.random((1, 1))

for j in xrange(500000):
    a2 = 1/(1 + np.exp(-(np.dot(x, w))))
    a3 = 1/(1 + np.exp(-(np.dot(a2, w2))))
    a4 = 1/(1 + np.exp(-(np.dot(a3, w3))))
    a4delta = (y - a4) * (a4 * (1 - a4))
    a3delta = a4delta.dot(w3.T) * (a3 * (1 - a3))
    a2delta = a3delta.dot(w2.T) * (a2 * (1 - a2))
    w3 += a3.T.dot(a4delta)
    w2 += a2.T.dot(a3delta)
    w += x.T.dot(a2delta)
print(a4)
```

Comment: Are you trying to determine whether the binary sequence ends in a 1?

Comment: Also, I'm a bit familiar with python, but I can't get your code to run because it thinks `0001` is an invalid token, perhaps because you have leading 0's. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the main problem is in the input - x in your case is a vector with one feature; I don't think model can learn from it. Why don't you make in a vector with 4 features?

```
x = np.array([
[0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1],
[0,0,1,0],
[0,1,0,0],
[1,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,1],
[0,1,1,0],
[1,1,0,0],
[1,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,1],
[1,1,1,0],
[1,1,0,1],
[1,0,1,1],
[1,1,1,1],
[1,1,1,1],
[1,1,1,1],
[1,1,1,1]
])
```

Also change weights shape:

```
w = np.random.random((4, 4))
w2 = np.random.random((4, 4))
w3 = np.random.random((4, 1))
```

With these changes the net gives good results.

Comment: Yup, I was going to suggest the same thing, but I couldn't get the code to run... glad it worked out!

Comment: Thank you very much the both of you, I will try this

Comment: What results did you get? I got exponential numbers like 3.55891306e-03.... not what I was hoping for...

Comment: I have made an example, here is it: https://gist.github.com/Erlemar/360bddedb91c0b9500e65566de2cbab3

Comment: @AndreyLukyanenko what results did you get? I got exponentials

Comment: Did you see my file? There are results in a second cell. Also 3.55891306e-03 = 0.00355891306, so it is almost 0.